Why are the user profile details not visible?
Unfortunately I am using IE8 and my profile details (usually to the left of the "search" bar) are not visible in quant.SE. I can see them in math.SE though - see links to screenshots below: 
Profile not visible in quant.SE
Profile visible in math.SE
Anyone experiencing the same problem? Pleas not that in the quant.SE screenshot I am definitely logged in (just to clear this up in advance). Refreshing won't work either.

Any chance you can take a picture of what you see? This is what I have.

@chrisaycock Of course. Edited.

Wow, that's trippy. I don't even see a login button. Can you test with a different browser? IE 9 works on my end.

@chrisaycock Thats the funny thing. It actually works with IE8. Thats what I wanted to show by enclosing the math.SE-picture. Terefore it must be a quant.se issue and thats why I posted it as bug here. But yes, it works with different browser as well.

Ok, this kind of thing needs to be brought-up on Meta.Stackoverflow, where the developers and designers can see the bug report. Can you post everything there that you listed here? Show the two pictures and explain what system you're using.

Is this still an issue or did it get resolved somewhere between December and now?

@Anna Lear Yes this is still an unresolved issue. But since I have no time to skim through all the IE8-related threads on meta.stackoverflow I am simply accepting the present situation.
